# Objective-C: How do you add together all the numbers stored in an array?

Tags: objective-c

So i am making a program  that will find the multiples of 3 and 5 under 1000.  Then it will store all the multiples to an array.  The final result is to add together all the values in the array and print it out.  Here is my code so far.

```
NSMutableArray *sums = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:25];


int a,b,i;

for (i = 0; i <= 1000; i++){
    a = i%3;
    b = i%5;

    if (a==0 || b==0){


        [sums addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];


    }
}


NSLog(@"\nThe sum of all the multiples of 3 and 5 between 1 and 1000 is %i", );
```

My question is: How can I add together all the values I have stored in the array "sums"?

Comment: added that.  i completely forgot because of thee code block

Comment: Only 2 questions to his name, but it's quite evident that this use does not want or know how to accept answers...

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan No,  it is problem one on project euler, a site that gives math problems to solve using programming.

Comment: @Daniel well i haven't found a solution to the problem yet...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSNumber *sum = [sums valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"];
NSLog(@"\nThe sum of all the multiples of 3 and 5 between 1 and 1000 is %i", [sum intValue]);
```

Comment: But where would i add this to the code? After the comma in the NSLog at the end, or at the beginning?

Comment: So if it do this, what would i put after the NSlog at the end to display the value?

Comment: @user1518915 Ok I have edited my answer to see how you can log the value.

Comment: Are you serious ? You would NSLog with the %@ token and pass the NSNumber. Did you try my example?

Comment: @Daniel Easy mate. He asked what to put into his `NSLog` and I just gave him the answer.

Comment: Also getting errors using this example.  Says im missing brackets.

Comment: @user1518915 You're also missing a semicolon in the end of your first line. Maybe that is the reason.

Comment: @Alladinian No I fixed that in my actual code.  Let me fix that in this code block.

Comment: @user1518915 I have just copy/pasted your code (with my answer) and it works just fine here. What errors do you get?

Comment: @Alladinian Ok this worked.  i am sorry, i deleted the @ inside the quotations because i thought it was a typo.  Thank you!

Comment: Sorry.  My bad.  Looks like the answer i came up with is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

**How to add together all numbers stored in an array?**

You could use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` for example:

```
int __block total = 0;

[myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    NSNumber *myNumber = (NSNumber*)obj;
    total += obj.intValue;
}];

NSLog(@"Total: %d", total);
```

Just be careful that you're using `NSNumbers` and if you needed to sue `floats` then adjust accordingly.